# What do I do on memory leak nodejs

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I was wondering what do I do if I found out when my app has memory leak. Is it safe to just restart my app or do I have to restart the server? Also, I think memwatch is not maintained anymore. Can you suggest any modules which is framework agnostic?

Comment: 99.9% of the time, you only have to restart your nodejs app to recover memory leaks since it is generally your app and not the OS that is leaking.  I have a simple server at home that I just automatically restart the node app at 4am every night.  The server box itself has been running continuously since the last power outage (many months ago).

Comment: memwatch could be not maintained anymore, but still helps. Check [this](http://www.nearform.com/nodecrunch/self-detect-memory-leak-node/) great article.